# Task queue task encounters "Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown" too frequently

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have jobs which process the records in GAE database and upload to google cloud. Since it is going to take a long time, so I use task queue to process a small batch at a time. But I have seen very consistently "Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown" problem in the log. I know I only have 30 seconds to cleanup and I am exceeding that time limit. While I understand that the instance may become unavailable and need shut down sometimes, but it happens so frequently like 3 or 4 minutes (occasionally 10 minutes which is the task queue time limit) into task execution every time, and not much work is done for each task.

I am wondering what might be the cause of the shut down of the backend. Is it purely server side issue or some bugs in the code might cause this problem as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`Process terminated because the backend took too long to shutdown` error usually shows up when new version of the backend is deployed. Also Google shuts down the backend instances quite often if you have the `<dynamic>true</dynamic>` option enabled. It does it even after few minutes even if they charge you for full 15 minutes so consider using permanent instead of dynamic instances.

Another problem might be that the instances run out of memory. In case of that the instances restart itself causing the error mentioned. You may try to use instance type with more memory such as B2 or B4.

Answer (score 0):

As Google say in IO backends will be shutdown without much warning. Developers are to code to handle fail situations where a task fails. In my case, I registered a shutdown hook which has worked everytime (only with task queues). In addition to that you can use tasknames to filter finished from failed tasks during recovery. GAE retires on its own. So not much worry of why the backend failed in the first place. As long as we use recovey code with task queues it will execute at some point.

As you mentioned it could be a bug or server load issues outside of apps. After chasing this error in different apps/code I feel GAE paradigm seems to be code around urlhandler for small task chunks.